# Perform Mysql Query that masks binary string at certain locations

Tags: mysql

This question is tough but what I am looking at doing is querying binary data to check occurrences. I can't use full-text search and I'm not sure that'd help anyhow, but say I have a string in the database like `00100` (but 256 characters long) and a user tries to search the database `00101`. Is there any way to find all of the rows that have a `1` in the 3rd position? Also, is there a way to do this with multiple position lookups (eg. a `1` for the 3rd and 5th position)?

I ask because I am trying to take five pieces of data and put them in one row of the database and not as five different rows. Each binary value is an boolean "occurrence" of an object, so `1` or `0`.

Update:

**Schema**

```
  `media_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `256_hash` text NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
```

I should have included this earlier but the actual 256 hash strings are 256 characters long. I'm assuming this it going to be a problem in the long run because its not indexable.

Sample records

```
media_id    palette_hash    sequence
1   00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000    1464423415
2   00000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000    1464423415
```

Comment: better to use MYSQL Proxy for masking information...

Comment: you need to post your schema and a few samples records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `REGEXP` comparison.

All rows with "1" in the third position:

```
#  The pattern reads: "anything twice, then 1, then anything"
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE (column REGEXP '^.{2}1.*$')
```

All rows with "1" in the third and fifth position:

```
#  The pattern reads: "anything twice, then 1, then anything once, then 1, then anything"
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE (column REGEXP '^.{2}1.1.*$')
```

Comment: On a million rows would regex be pretty slow?

Comment: Compared to what? And is this a general question? Or are you really dealing with a million rows?

Comment: I am dealing with that many rows. Essentially I'd compare it to a lookup `column = "00101"` which would use an index. I should test this first and see for myself.

Comment: Let me know what you find

Comment: I tested that pattern on just a few thousand strings and was getting 200ms queries—so it started getting slow as I added more strings. Part of which could be because my data is 256 numbers long and is too long to fit as an INT or binary and I also couldn't use an index on it... definitely something for me to think about here.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a large string. If speed is a factor, this is information you'll want to include in your original question.